# SpringXD - File Splitter - Slow on Rabbit transport, file contents not using new line property

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-xd

We have a use case to split file of 10 M lines into small files of 10000 each. We are planning to use SpringXD. We are facing following issues:

1. Back up the input file
2. FileName has to be generated based on inputFile Name and Counter like refdata-1.txt, refdata-2.txt etc.
3. File Contents is not written with new line and is concatenated with ",".
4. Process to split is taking around 45 minutes using rabbit as transport in single node but 4 minutes in local transport in Single node.

`stream create --name fileTestDirExp --definition "file --outputType=text/plain --dir=/Documents --pattern=createdTest.txt --mode=lines --maxMessages=5000 | aggregator --aggregation=#this.![payload] --count=10000 --release='#this.size() eq 10000' |sink:file --dirExpression='''/Documents/splitter/''+new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(''yyyyMMdd'').format(new java.util.Date()).toString()' --nameExpression='headers[''id'']+''.txt'''" --deploy`

Any help in fixing the above issues is appreciated.

Regards
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You are sending every line over rabbitmq. Consider composing the `file | aggregator` into a composed module so they are co-located and only the aggregated data is transported over Rabbit.

The aggregator emits a `List<String>`; so I don't see how you can write that to the file sink; it only accepts payloads of type `String`, `byte[]` or `File`.

You will need a custom transformer to transform the list to a single string, or add another splitter (composed with the file sink) and use append mode.